# Android camera issue on samsung galaxy s2

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I have developed a small demo in which i am using the android camera. what my demo do is take picture from camera and on Ok button it sends the image to my server.

I have tried my application on different devices and all of them except one gives three buttons. Ok, Retake and Cancel after taking the picture. but only samsung galaxy s2 gives the save and delete button.

does anybody know what could be a problem. because my app is working fine on every device except this samasung galaxy 2. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively,

- Delete -> Retake
- Save -> Ok
- Back hardware button -> Cancel

so everything should be OK. Else, could you tell us what Delete etc represents in terms of Ok etc?